# Why does my Windows open CSS file with notepad?

Tags: file-extension

In CMD I get this:

```
C:\>assoc .css
.css=CSSfile

C:\>ftype CSSfile
File type 'CSSfile' not found or no open command associated with it.
```

But in explorer, CSS files have icon and I can double click and notepad is used to open it. Why does my Windows open CSS file with notepad?

**I'm not asking HOW to open a file with certain program. I'm asking WHY .css file is associated with notepad**, given "File type 'CSSfile' not found or no open command associated with it" ftype command tells.

Comment: ...because Windows is dumb?

Comment: install visual studio and see what happens. This is a joke... VS takes forever to start and it's the default for a lot of file types (xml).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Why does my Windows open CSS file with notepad?

Right click on the CSS file and click "Open With" > "Choose default program..."

You will see the the default program is set to "Notepad":

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

You can use this dialog to change the default application if you wish to do so.

In the registry the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.css` has value `PerceivedType` set to `text`:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Warning:

- Do not modify this entry. It is mentioned only to explain why Notepad is the default program.

Notepad is the default application for opening text files.

You can open the css file in a `cmd` shell by typing it's name and it will also open in notepad:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

#### Why Notepad is the default application for opening text files?

> If I have VIM, how do I make VIM the default application for extensions whose PerceivedType is text?

Notepad is registered as the command to be executed for files of perceived type text.

To change the command to `vim` edit the registry values described below and replace `%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE` with the path to `vim.exe`.

> **Registering a Perceived Type**
>
> Registry values for perceived types are defined as subkeys of the
>   `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations` registry subkey.
>
> For example, the perceived type text is registered as follows:
>
> ```
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
>    SystemFileAssociations
>       text
>          shell
>             edit
>                command
>                   (Default) = "%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE" "%1"
>             open
>                command
>                   (Default) = "%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE" "%1"
> ```
>
> A file type's perceived type is indicated by including a
>   `PerceivedType` value in the file type's subkey. The `PerceivedType`
>   value is set to the name of the perceived type registered under
>   `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations` registry subkey, as shown
>   in the previous registry example.
>
> To declare .cpp files as being of perceived type "text", for example,
>   add the following registry entry:
>
> ```
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
>    .cpp
>       PerceivedType = text
> ```

Source [Application Registration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: He wants to open with command line. And he can literally just right click to change the default program instead of manually changing the registry?

Comment: @ytpillai You can open from the command line. Read the answer carefully.

Comment: @ytpillai Yes, you can change the default program (if you so wish) by right-clicking.

Comment: Apologies I did not read carefully. Your answer is an interesting one where he does not need to write anything else. But why did you discredit mine? Doesn't my answer essentially do the same thing except with two more words? I don't want to discredit yours, only understand why I am wrong

Comment: Right, so isn't it better to use an easier solution (in response to your second comment). I think that registry may be a bit overboard and OP has a large chance of messing up his system if he is not experienced

Comment: @ytpillai The question is "Why does my Windows open CSS file with notepad?". Your answer did not explain **why**.

Comment: @ytpillai The registry entry is only there to explain the **why**. He did not ask how to change anything and I did not suggest modifying the registry. I will add a warning to the answer just in case.

Comment: In a way aren't we both saying the same thing except you go more in detail

Comment: @ytpillai Only because you changed your answer after my comment.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Yes I did take it. Do I still deserve a down vote

Comment: Downvote and initial comment removed.

Comment: At ease, I'm not novice. The most valuable part in your answer is "Notepad is the default application for opening text files." So the question is why Notepad is the default application for opening text files? If I have VIM, how do I make VIM the default application for extensions whose PerceivedType is text?

Comment: @LoveRight I'm in a good mood so I will answer your new question. See the updated answer.

Comment: Excellent! I assume if HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CSSfile has shell\open key, it will override the one specified in perceived type. Am I right?

Comment: @LoveRight I believe so. I haven't tested it.